# Edit Wamp "localhost" page

Tags: apache, wamp

I wanted to reorganize my Wamp and add a section "My Laravel projects" without adding an extra "index.php" in "www" folder.
After searching and searching, I didn't find any solutions or a folder that contains information/code of the "www" page.

How it looks right now:

[image]

How I want to organize it:

[image]

Is it possible? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should never amend or add anything to the `\wamp\www` folder.

Instead, if you add a subfolder like `wamp\www\laravelproject` or a folder in a completely different folder structure like `c:\website\project1\www` and then create a Virtual Host for each project. you will then automatically see the new Virtual Host mentioned on the WAMPServer homepage.

See this post for how to easily create [Apache Virtual Hosts is WAMPServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I might do it in your way, if there's no other way. What's the explanation for this "You should never amend or add anything to the \wamp\www folder."?

Comment: That folder is for WAMPServer's use only. Always create a subfolder or a totally seperate folder for your site(s). If you overwrite the `index.php` in the `www` (which almost everything will want to do) you loose the use of the WAMPServer homepage, which has many uses you might miss not having